# my fragment cannot show recyclerview and data from json url

Tags: json, android-studio, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-volley

I have been using the notifychanged() after call add . and there is no error in my logcat. loaddata() to load data without JSON url. and get data() to load data from json url. please help me. my android manifest has been set for android permission.  I am confused. I follow all the way to show my recyclerview but there is no way to show the data. I use url from heroku. and the json show. can you show me how to solve my problem? thank you very much before. :)

This is my home fragment

```
package com.android.herry.combile;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.textclassifier.TextLinks;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class FragmentHome extends Fragment {
    private RecyclerView listevent;
    private LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;
    private EventAdapter eventListAdapter;
    private Context context;
    private RecyclerView mList;

    private final static String url= "https://guarded-scrubland-29104.herokuapp.com/index.php?action=show_data";

    public static FragmentHome newInstance(){
        return new FragmentHome();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        this.context = context;
    }
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        listevent = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listEvent);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
        eventListAdapter = new EventAdapter();
        listevent.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        listevent.setAdapter(eventListAdapter);

        getData();
    }

    private void loadData(){
        List<Event> memberList = new ArrayList<>();
        Event member;

        int thumb[] = {R.drawable.ic_account, R.drawable.ic_account, R.drawable.ic_account,
                R.drawable.ic_account, R.drawable.ic_account, R.drawable.ic_account,
                R.drawable.ic_account, R.drawable.ic_account, R.drawable.ic_account,
                R.drawable.ic_account, R.drawable.ic_account, R.drawable.ic_account,
                R.drawable.ic_account, R.drawable.ic_account, R.drawable.ic_account,
                R.drawable.ic_account, R.drawable.ic_account, R.drawable.ic_account,
                R.drawable.ic_account, R.drawable.ic_account};

        String name[] = {"Ayana Shahab", "Beby Chaesara Anadila", "Delima Rizky", "Dena Siti Rohyati",
                "Elaine Hartanto", "Frieska Anastasia Laksani", "Gabriella M. W.", "Ghaida Farisya",
                "Jennifer Rachel Natasya", "Jessica Vania Widjaja", "Jessica Veranda", "Melody Nurramdhani Laksani",
                "Nabilah Ratna Ayu Azalia", "Rezky Wiranti Dhike", "Sendy Ariani", "Shania Junianatha",
                "Shinta Naomi", "Sofia Meifaliani", "Sonia Natalia", "Thalia Ivanka Elizabeth"};

        String team = "Team J";

        for(int i=0; i < thumb.length; i++){
            member = new Event();
            member.setId(i+1);
            member.setTitle(name[i]);
            member.setDetail(team);
            member.setPic(thumb[i]);

            memberList.add(member);
        }
        eventListAdapter.addAll(memberList);
    }


    private void getData(){
        final List<Event> listitem = new ArrayList<>();
        final Event item=new Event();
        final String[] ocha = new String[1];
        StringRequest jsonArrayRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {


                JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                try {
                    jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Records");

                    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                        jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(i);
                        item.setTitle(jsonObject.getString("event_id"));
                        item.setDetail(jsonObject.getString("detail"));
                        item.setId(jsonObject.getInt("event_id"));

                        ocha[0] =jsonObject.getString("event_id")+ocha;
                     //   Log.e("ochantik", String.valueOf(ocha));

                        listitem.add(item);
                        eventListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    }

                    listevent.setAdapter(eventListAdapter);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }
                }



        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("Volley", error.toString());

            }
        });
        RequestQueue requestQueue =  Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);



    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
    }
}
```

this is  Event.java

```
package com.android.herry.combile;

import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

public class Event implements Parcelable {
    private int id;
    private String title;
    private String detail;
    private int pic;

    protected Event(Parcel in) {
        id = in.readInt();
        title = in.readString();
        detail = in.readString();
        pic= in.readInt();
    }


    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Event> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Event>() {
        @Override
        public Event createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Event(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Event[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Event[size];
        }
    };

    public Event() {

    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDetail() { return detail; }

    public void setDetail(String detail) { this.detail = detail; }

    public int getPic() { return pic; }

    public void setPic(int pic) {
        this.pic = pic;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeInt(id);
        dest.writeString(title);
        dest.writeString(detail);
        dest.writeInt(pic);
    }
}
```

and this is my adapter

```
package com.android.herry.combile;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class EventAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<EventAdapter.EventViewHolder> {
    private List<Event> eventList;

    public EventAdapter() {
        eventList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    private void add(Event item) {
        eventList.add(item);
        notifyItemInserted(eventList.size() - 1);
    }


    public void addAll(List<Event> eventList) {
        for (Event event : eventList) {
            add(event);
        }
    }

    public void remove(Event item) {
        int position = eventList.indexOf(item);
        if (position > -1) {
            eventList.remove(position);
            notifyItemRemoved(position);
        }
    }

    public void clear() {
        while (getItemCount() > 0) {
            remove(getItem(0));
        }
    }

    public Event getItem(int position) {
        return eventList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public EventViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.event_list, parent, false);
        EventViewHolder memberViewHolder = new EventViewHolder(view);
        return memberViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(EventViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Event event = eventList.get(position);

        holder.EventPic.setImageResource(event.getPic());
        holder.EventTitle.setText(event.getTitle());
        holder.EventDetail.setText(event.getDetail());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return eventList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetachedFromRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onDetachedFromRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    static class EventViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView EventPic;
        TextView EventTitle;
        TextView EventDetail;

        public EventViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            EventPic = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Event_pic);
            EventTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Event_Title);
            EventDetail = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Event_Detail);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _"can you show me how to solve my problem."_ Probably you should debug your code to check all the steps in the process. Now we just have a lot of code and don't know exactly where it fails and how. Do you even get the data? Do you get the data, but it's not updating on the UI? Etc.